# Jquery calculating sum with dynamic IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a google map and when a user adds a marker, it calculates the distance between that marker and the previous marker. I am adding the distances to a table via jQuery. The distances work fine. I want to have an "accumulated distance column where it adds the distances up to that point. So it looks like this:

[image]

I am dynamically assigning ids to the spans on each row. I am not sure how to go about creating the accumulated distance column. This is what I have done so far:

```
 var currentIndex=0;
 var distancenm = Math.round((((google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(FromLocation, ToLocation))/1000)) * 0.539957);
 var accdistance = $("#distance_0").val();
 var accdistance2 = $("#distance_1").val();
 var accdistancetotal = (accdistance+accdistance2);

 $('#table').append('<tr id="table_row_'+(currentIndex-1)+'">'+
    '<td><span id="distance_'+(currentIndex-1)+'" name="distance_[]" class="distance">'+distancenm+' </span></td>'+
    '<td><span id="accdistance_'+(currentIndex-1)+'" name="accdistance_[]" class="accumulateddistance">'+accdistancetotal+' </span></td>'+
    '</td>'
```

I also don't know how to select the ID without directly referencing it like this:

```
$("#distance_0").val();
```

because I won't know how many points the user will add. So I need to have it in such a way that each row's accumulated distance column is just the sum of the current row's distance column + the previous row's distance column.

EDIT: It looks like this after Mario's suggestion:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum all your current distances you need to do that:

```
var accDistance = 0;
$('.distance').each(function() {
  accDistance += parseInt($(this).text());
});
accDistance += distancenm;
```

I think it will work because in your example you are using `val()` in a `<span>` tag, it is incorrect.

Comment: Oh I see. I tried your code and it works but I have issues with the first accumulated distance row which shows 0. it basically skips one. I'll edit my question and post an image of what it looks like

Comment: Please check my edit, you need to sum the total distance accumulated with your distancenm variable.